# C# AForge.Video decoding MJPEG stream over websockets

Tags: c#, websocket, video-streaming, aforge, mjpeg

I'm trying to display an MJPEG video stream on my WPF C# application.
The MJPEG decoder library I'm using is [AForge.Video](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AForge.Video).
So far I've managed to display video streamed over http with this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using AForge.Video;

namespace VideoControl
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MJPEGStream stream;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stream = new MJPEGStream("http://mylocaladdress:1220/video");                      //Only works over http: and not ws:.
            stream.NewFrame += GetNewFrame;
            stream.Start();
        }
        void GetNewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)e.Frame.Clone();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {imgStream.Source = BitmapToImageSource(bmp);});        //Convert bitmap to image source first before applying to image.
        }
        BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapimage.BeginInit();
                bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
                bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapimage.EndInit();
                return bitmapimage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, my goal is to get the video stream over websockets (ws) instead of http. How would i go about implementing the websocket (ws) protocol for this library? Simply replacing the http address with a websocket address doesn't work, since the library doesn't understand the websocket protocol.

I'm hosting my stream on a Node-RED server using [this](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-custom-ffmpeg-video) FFMPEG wrapper.
The video stream shows up fine in browser, but not in C#.
The earlier successful tests i conducted over http were streamed using [streameye](https://github.com/ccrisan/streameye).
Are there any alternative MJPEG decoders to [AForge.Video](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AForge.Video) that support websockets out of the box?

Comment: you could use EMGU.CV i used it years ago for something like this.

Comment: @DenisSchaf Is EMGU.CV capable of consuming video streams over websockets (ws://)?

Comment: Does this help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng My C# program works as a websocket client, not a server. Thank you for your input regardless.

Comment: The server (listener) must be changed to recognize ws. A ws client cannot talk to a httpserver.  Someplace you have to make the transition.

Comment: @jdweng As I said. when i first hosted my video stream over http with streameye, the AForge.Video implementation worked fine. But now that I'm hosting my webcam over websockets instead of http, my code fails to retrieve any data. The websocket stream however displays just fine with jsmpeg in javascript, so the data streamed by my webcam server is comprehensible by javascript websocket implementations at least. For now I'm just trying to get this to work on C# too.

Comment: jsmpeg is using a relay.  See : https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg?force_isolation=true#streaming-via-websockets

Comment: @jdweng So how would i approach this? I'm thinking in circles here.

Comment: I is probably better to just use HTTP since server doesn't support websocket.  The jsmpeg is adding another layer of software to convert http to websocket (the relay).  If you really want to use websocket you would have to write your own relay method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MJpeg is designed to broadcast over an HTTP request. Its parsing methodology changes according to the content type header, which you will not have in WebSockets. I do not think any library support this out of box, but you can create a workaround like jsmpeg (thanks @jdweng) did.

- Your application creates a simple HTTP server that serves MJpeg stream for the AForge.Video ()
- You connect to your video source over WebSockets and stream that result to your HTTP endpoint
- Connect AForge.Video instance to your local web server, voila everything works.

Or

you can write your own stream decoder based on AForge's own [MJPegStream (GitHub)](https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET/blob/master/Sources/Video/MJPEGStream.cs) stream reader.